# Number of roots of $f(x) = s f(x+B)$ for specific $f(x)$

Tags: roots

For real function $f(x)=\frac{x^\beta}{1+\alpha x^\beta}$ with real $\alpha \ge 1$ and real $\beta>0$ I suppose that equation
$$f(x) = sf(x+B)$$
for real $B$ with $0<B<1$ and real $s$ with $0<s\le 1$ has at most a single solution in $x$ within the interval $0\le x \le 1$. Any ideas, how this could be proven?

Comment: Consider $f(x+B)/f(x)$ and prove that it is strictly decreasing at $0< x \leq 1$

Comment: Moreover, interval can be extended to $0<x<\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Great! That's it. Thanks a lot, Ivan.
The derivative of $f(x+b)/f(x)$ is

$$\frac{\beta x^{-\beta - 1} (B + x)^{\beta - 1} (\alpha ( x^{\beta + 1}-(B + x)^{\beta + 1}) - B)}{(\alpha (B + x)^\beta + 1)^2}$$

See [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B%28%28x%2BB%29%5Eb*%281%2Ba*x%5Eb%29%29%2F%28%281%2Ba*%28x%2BB%29%5Eb%29*x%5Eb%29%2Cx%5D)

All factors are always postive except $(\alpha ( x^{\beta + 1}-(B + x)^{\beta + 1}) - B)$ which is always negative given the restrictions on parameter values from above. Thus,  $f(x+b)/f(x)$ is strictly decreasing and can intersect with constant $s$ at most once.